# What is a perma link and what is it's purpose

Tags: support, chat

During a chat there is a small drop down and clicking on this drop down gives the details of the message like when it was posted and the options to flag,star

[image: Options when clicking the drop down button in the chat]

What is the permalink option in that box.

[image: the star this message,flag as spam/offensive options which appear in every message]

Also i find the star,flag options appear twice once in the drop down and the second in the message.Do they differ or it's another reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

permalink is a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of Permanent and Link.

It is a link that takes you directly to the specific chat message, whether it is still on the "front page" of chat or not.

The word has common usage on blogs, forums as more.

In the words of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink):

> A permalink (portmanteau of permanent link) is a URL that points to a specific web page, often a blog or forum entry which has passed from the front page to the archives, or the result of a search in a database. Because a permalink remains unchanged indefinitely, it is less susceptible to link rot.

Comment: what about the dual display in star,flag do they differ in their function or for some other reason

Comment: @user285oo6 - I don't quite follow. Star something you like, flag something if it requires moderator attention.

Comment: @user285oo6 the dual display is for your own convenience, so you can do it both by just hovering or by clicking and choosing from the popup.